# Asymptotically $n(1-\frac{a\log n}{n})^{n/2-1}(1-\frac{b\log n}{n})^{n/2}\sim n^{1-\frac{a+b}{2}}$

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose $a,b>0$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}<1$

Why is the following relation true as $n\rightarrow\infty $ $$n(1-\frac{a\log n}{n})^{n/2-1}(1-\frac{b\log n}{n})^{n/2}\sim n^{1-\frac{a+b}{2}}$$

The $1$ in the exponent on the right hand side value is obviously clear... So Why does $(1-\frac{a\log n}{n})^{n/2}(1-\frac{b\log n}{n})^{n/2}$ reduce to $n^{\frac{a+b}{2}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use $\left ( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n \sim e^x$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y=\left(1-a\frac{ \log (n)}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$$
$$\log(y)=\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)\log\left(1-a\frac{ \log (n)}{n}\right)\sim -\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)a\frac{ \log (n)}{n}$$
So, taking the logarithm of the rhs of you expression $A$ we have
$$\log(A)\sim \log(n)-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)a\frac{ \log (n)}{n}-\frac n 2 b \frac{ \log (n)}{n}$$ Expanding and grouping
$$\log(A) \sim \left(1-\frac{a+b}{2} \right) \log (n)+a\frac{ \log (n)}{n}\sim \left(1-\frac{a+b}{2} \right) \log (n)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)} \sim n^{1-\frac{a+b}{2}}$$